# R: generating random points using csr

Tags: r, random, polygon

I have a polygon map of Mozambique, along with administrative districts. I'd like to generate 10 random points *within* each district. I am using R's csr function, but it isn't working:

```
library(splancs)   
for (f in Mozambique$NAME_1){
        Points=csr(f,10)
    }
```

I keep getting the error "Error in poly[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions". What should I do to diagnose and fix this problem?

Comment: When I use `sos::findFn` to search for packages and functions with that function name I get: `splancs  csr  Generate completely spatially random points on a polygon` You SHOULD indicate what packages your functions come from by including an informative  `library()` call.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that, in the call to csr(), f needs to be a polygon.  If "Mozambique" contains the list of polygon vertices representing each district and if "f" is the counter, then you could do:

```
library(splancs)
pts <- list()
for (f in 1:length(Mozambique)) {
    district <- Mozambique[[f]]
    pts <- rbind(pts, csr(district,10))
}
```